# Could you topologically sort a complete acyclic directed graph through classical sorting algorithms like quicksort?

Tags: algorithm, graph, quicksort, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

If you have a complete directed acyclic graph (i.e each vertex has either an ongoing or outgoing edge with any other vertex), you can topologically sort it with the classic topological sort algorithm in O(V+E) = O(V^2) since E = O(V^2).

But could we sort it in O(V log V) through a classic O(n log n) algorithm like quicksort? Since we can always compare two vertices I have the impression this would work. Any counterexample?

Also I guess this could only work if the graph is complete. Even if the graph is almost complete then you can end up having two compare two vertices that don't have an edge.

Comment: The comparison is likely to not be constant time.

Comment: Your graph defines something that is very nearly a total order on the set of vertices (the only thing missing are the self-edges on each vertex, but I think we can get by without them). I think that is sufficient.

Comment: @user58697 : "The comparison is likely to not be constant time" => why though? if you have an adjacency matrix you can know the direction of the edge in O(1). Even without adjacency matrix, if you store the neighbors of an vertex in a hashset the you can check in O(1) too.

Comment: Misread the question. Please disregard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the input graph is acyclic, then it defines a strict weak ordering where *a* < *b* if and only if there is an arc from *a* to *b*, and quicksort will give you the unique topological order.

In general, however, you can't test whether a tournament is acyclic without probing all of the arc directions.